# Python: multiple inheritance and properties

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance

I've been working on a client/server TCP application of which here's a rough outline:

```
config_type = namedtuple('config', ['host', 'port'])


class Server:

    def __init__(self, config: config_type):
        self.config = config


class Client:

    def __init__(self, config: config_type):
        self.config = config
```

Now I'm expanding this architecture to other computers, so I'm implementing a 'slave' server that will run on the other hosts and distribute messages from the master to the clients on that host, so I wrote something like this:

```
class SlaveServer(Server, Client):

    def __init__(self, master_server_config: config_type, slave_server_config: config_type):
        Client.__init__(self, master_server_config)
        Server.__init__(self, slave_server_config)
```

However, since my `Client` and `Server` classes define a property called config it appears that the last init call wins:

```
master = config_type('localhost', 4342)
slave_config = config_type('localhost', 6555)

slave = SlaveServer(master, slave_config)

print(f'master={master}')
print(f'slave_config={slave_config}')
print(f'slave.config={slave.config}')
```

Outputs:

```
master=config(host='localhost', port=4342)
slave_config=config(host='localhost', port=6555)
slave.config=config(host='localhost', port=6555)
```

Which obviously will break things.

How is multiple inheritance supposed to be used in this kind of situation? Am I expected to make sure myself that conflicting property names do not exist? Perhaps in this case multiple inheritance is a bad idea and I should change `SlaveServer` so it doesn't use inheritance, and instead just has two properties, `server` and `client`.

Comment: Multiple inheritance is dangerous territory.  You might consider whether this would be better served by being a container: have `SlaveServer` contain an instance of `Client` and an instance of `Server`.  Why don't you just have the remote clients contact the master server directly?  What do you gain by inserting a go-between?

Comment: @TimRoberts 'What do you gain by inserting a go-between?' in this case, experience! This just a hobby project partly to learn python.

Comment: This looks like a poor design. Consider containment instead of inheritance

Comment: @MadPhysicist I understand that, and I've already changed this particular hobby project. But I'm still curious about what people are expected to do with conflicting property names in multiple inheritance situations.

Comment: @IanNewson. They are not expected to use multiple inheritance in that situation :) When you encounter poor design, do what you must, but try to change it when you have the time.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Yes, I've already changed, I was just playing around with Python while learning. I probably should have used a different example as my example seems to have distracted almost everyone from the actual question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you own all the code in there, you can use the name-mangling feature of Python:
Just prefix the attributes and methods that would conflict with two `__` in their name, and do nto try to touch those on the child classes (just on the very class where they are defined).

The double `__` prefix triggers a build-time feature that changes the name of the attribute to include the class where they are defined as a prefix, in a transparent way - therefore both `Server` and `Client` can each see their own `__config` attribute. And if you try to reach for `.__config` on `ClientServer` you will get an `AttributeError`- but you can try and access each of them by using the mangled names:

```
from collections import namedtuple


config_type = namedtuple('config', ['host', 'port'])


class Server:

    def __init__(self, config: config_type):
        self.__config = config


class Client:

    def __init__(self, config: config_type):
        self.__config = config


class SlaveServer(Server, Client):

    def __init__(self, master_server_config: config_type, slave_server_config: config_type):
        Client.__init__(self, master_server_config)
        Server.__init__(self, slave_server_config)
```

And upon instantiating this on the REPL we can verify both attributes are saved:

```
In [65]: a = SlaveServer((0,0), (1,1))

In [67]: print(a._Server__config)
(1, 1)

In [68]: print(a._Client__config)
(0, 0)
```

**disclaimer**: I am not judging your architecture, just pointing you to a solution built-in the language for this kind of attribute access in multiple inheritance. Even without seeing more of your code, this seems a text-book clear example where composition should be used over inheritance,.

Comment: Thanks, that's handy to know. Btw I've already changed the example I used to use composition.